# @variables not working in css3

Tags: css

I'm attempting to setup generic variables in my css file that I can call throughout it just so I can keep things clean and the same.

Example:

```
@shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

.shadow {
    box-shadow: @shadow inset;
}
```

When I attempt to apply .shadow to to an element, it doesn't show the shadow on my page. When I right click and view Elements in chrome I see .shadow is crossed out with the statement "Invalid property value".

Keep in mind shadow is just an example, I have the same issue with width, height, etc.

I've looked at JSFiddle pages that use the same method and it works fine in this chrome browser, so I don't believe its the browser's problem.

Comment: That's not css, not even css4. try less, stylus...

Comment: Where did read this would be supported? (I really wish it was supported.)

Comment: Variables are a CSS preprocessor (like SCSS, LESS) feature, not a native CSS feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can only declare variables with CSS pre-processors like LESS or SASS. CSS3 doesn't offer a variable declaration rule.

Maybe in your JSFiddle pages included these pre-processors so you might be confused.